# Missing required parameters for [Route: products.show] [URI: products/{product}]

Tags: laravel-6

please i need your help i am using Laravel 6
I got this problem after change my html code from unordered list to a table, i had checked the view code but i do not see the error

This is my index view

```
<table class="table">
            <thead class="simba-thead">
                <tr>
                    <th>Codigo Interno / Codigo de Parte</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Percha / Bodega</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Activo</th>
                    <th>Editar / Eliminar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @forelse($products as $product)
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{route('products.show',$product)}}">{{$product->internalCode}}</a><br>{{$product->partNumber}}</td>
                    <td>{{$product->description}}</td>
                    <td>{{$product->rack}}<br>{{$product->warehouse}}</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>{{$product->Price}}</td>
                    <td>{{$product->Active}}</td>
                    <td>edit/delete</td>
                </tr>
                @empty
                    <td>null</td>
                    <td>null</td>
                    <td>null</td>
                    <td>null</td>
                    <td>null</td>
                    <td>null</td>
                    <td>null</td>
                </tr>
                @endforelse
                {{$products->links()}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My controller

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('products.index',[
            'products'=>Product::latest()->paginate()
        ]);
    }
    public function show(Product $product){
        return view('products.show',[
            'product'=>$product
        ]);
    }
}
```

My route

```
Route::resource('products','ProductController')->names('products');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Laravel uses the field name 'id' by default to id primary key in tables.
I solve it add this line to my model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'productId';
```